# How to set up three readonly database server (postgresql, mongodb and elastic search) in django project?

Tags: django, database

Actually I am having a problem in **`DJANGO project`**. I want extract some information from read only database server.
 I have three  database server :

```
Postgresql
MongoDB 
Elasticsearch
```

How to add these server in setting.py and check the connectivity in utility program. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can define as many dbs as you want in settings.py if your django version is >1.2.

```
DATABASES = {
  'db1': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'your_db_name',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'blababla',
    'HOST': 'yourhost',
    'PORT': '',
  },
  'db2': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mondgodb',
    'NAME': 'your_db_name',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'blababla',
    'HOST': 'yourhost',
  }
  'db3': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.django_elasticsearch',
    'NAME': 'your_db_name',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'blababla',
    'HOST': 'yourhost',
  }
}
```

I am not sure what `ENGINE`-name to add for mongodb and elasticsearch, you should search for it.

and django doesnot provide any option to make your db readonly, i think you need to play with user permissions for db connections.

Comment: How to access theses database in program side?

Comment: @BirendraKumar ``settings.DATABASES['db1']['NAME']``

Answer (score 0):

Support of MongoDb and ElasticSearch are included in a fork of django project:

[Django for non-relational databases](http://github.com/aparo/django-nonrel)

Integrate a readonly postgres db is possibile with the standard Django release. First you should add your databases in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'dbname',
    'USER': 'username1',
    'PASSWORD': 'password1',
    'HOST': 'host1',
    'PORT': '',
  },
  'ro_db': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'ro_dbname',
    'USER': 'username2',
    'PASSWORD': 'password2',
    'HOST': 'host2',
    'PORT': '',
  },
}
```

if you have more than one readonly db you can add other entries for those.
Then maybe you would set up an app to manage your ro_db data and a add a router for that:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [CustomRouter(), ]
```

where you can define CustomRouter as follow

```
class CustomRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'ro_db_manager_app':
            return 'ro_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        You maybe want to write some data for testing purpose.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'ro_db_manager_app':
            return 'ro_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'ro_db_manager_app' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'ro_db_manager_app':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        if db == 'ro_db':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'ro_db_manager_app'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'ro_db_manager_app':
            return False
        return None
```

See [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/) for more info about multiple db management.

At this point you can inspect your ro_db and create its models

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database ro_db > models.py
```

You can note that models present in this files have a meta attribute

```
managed = False
```

and it means that django won't attempt to create this model.
See ["Integrating Django with a legacy database"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/legacy-databases/) for more info about this point.